# TIC SSL Trust Error while trying to read a txt file

Tags: ios, swift, http

I'm having this problem with reading from a txt file from a website without a certificate even though I have allowed it in Info.plist.

My Swift code looks like this:

```
let url = URL(string: "http://newskit.matsworld.io/domaci/text.txt")!

let task = URLSession.shared.downloadTask(with: url) { localURL, urlResponse, error in
    if let localURL = localURL {
        if let string = try? String(contentsOf: localURL) {
            print(string)
        }
    }
}

task.resume()
```

And the Info.plist looks like this:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
    <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
    <dict>
        <key>http://newskit.matsworld.io</key>
        <dict>
            <key>ExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
            <true/>
            <key>IncludesSubdomains</key>
            <true/>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

I'm stuck with this and can't figure it out. Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `domain` key is supposed to be just the domain without the scheme (`http`) and without subdomains if `IncludesSubdomains` is specified

```
<key>matsworld.io</key>
```

Comment: Thanks, but it's still dropping the same error and `NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9813)`

Comment: I just tested it quickly and I got an *HTTP load failed (error code: -1003* error. Seems to be a dns issue.

Comment: Huge thanks! That was the problem. I've figured it out.